# Converting IPAddress array to HTML

Tags: powershell

```
$NetConf = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.IPAddress -ne $null} | select IPAddress| ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property IPAddress -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>IP config</h2>"
```

How to convert this output

```
172.17.7.97, fe80::4da6:ae96:zzzz:zzzz
10.0.75.1, fe80::1063:f3b7:52:zzzz    
192.168.0.107, fe80::7d9f:d8d:zzzz:zzz
```

to table like:

```
MacAddress    IPAddress     Description
xx.xx.xx.xx   10.0.75.1     asdasdasdasd
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where do you store that output in? What is Description `asdasdasdasd` and where it should fit? Please include all the necessary information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something you shouldn't even be getting that original output you're showing us. Not with how you select your property.

However, I believe the following does what you are asking.

Or are you asking on how to exclude IPv6 in your output as well?

Edited to add a few different variants.

```
# Both IPv4 & IPv6, combined.
$NetConf1 = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
    where { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } | 
    select MacAddress, @{N="IPAddress";E={$_.IPAddress -join "," }}, Description | 
    ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property MacAddress, IPAddress, Description -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>IP config</h2>"

# Both IPv4 & IPv6, separated.
$NetConf2 = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } | 
    select MacAddress, 
    @{N="IPv4Address";E={ $_.IPAddress | where { ([ipaddress]($_)).AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'  }}},
    @{N="IPv6Address";E={ $_.IPAddress | where { ([ipaddress]($_)).AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetworkV6'}}},
    Description | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property MacAddress, IPv4Address, IPv6Address, Description -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>IP config</h2>"

# IPv4 only
$NetConf3 = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } |
    select MacAddress,
    @{N="IPAddress";E={ $_.IPAddress | where { ([ipaddress]($_)).AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'  }}},
    Description | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property MacAddress, IPAddress, Description -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>IP config</h2>"
```

Comment: I am very appreciated. And if it possible show how to split IPv4 and IPv6. Thank you very much.

Comment: Edited to add a few different variations.

Comment: @ExLibris Feel free to mark this answer as a solution to your question if it solved your problem.